# AMP html - switch an image to another image periodically every a few seconds

Tags: amp-html

I want to switch an image to another image every a few seconds on AMP.

I've tried it using `amp-script`, for example, changing its `src`, `backgroundImage`, or append a new `img` with higher `z-index` to hide previous image.

But all of them were failed and the console said:

> [amp-script] amp-script[script="main"].js was terminated due to illegal mutation.

or

> [amp-script] Sanitized [src]="./gallery1.jpeg": ...

So, Is it possible to switch an image to another in AMP? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options:

1. Use amp-carousel (it'll have a slide animation though):
2. Use amp-script: mutations are always accepted for amp-script elements with [layout!="container"] and height < 300px.
3. Define a CSS animation that'll cycle through the images (e.g. [here is a sample](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/#cfimg3) that would work the same way in AMP).

I'd recommend going with either 1. or 3. as these are easiest to implement with least runtime overhead.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I think the third option you suggested is enough and appropriate for my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `amp-script` for this because you have to mutate the DOM by itself and not by user interaction which isn't possible with AMP.

You can achieve this with CSS via animations (if you need a cycle of images).